# Bluetooth keyboard glitches when pressing space

Tags: external-keyboard

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, running Marshmallow.  For some reason, when I use my bluetooth keyboard, I get an intermittent error when pressing space (or any punctuation).  As near as I can tell, when it does happen, it is when I press space after a mispelled word (or one which is not in the dictionary) or a number.  When it happens, it moves the cursor to the beginning of the mispelled word.

For example, if I type '2017', then hit space, the cursor will jump to the beginning, like so '|2017'.  As you can imagine, this is incredibly annoying.  When typing my email address, it jumps 3 backwards times.

I know this is incredibly specific, so there might not be an answer.  If I remember correctly, it may have started happening when I added another language to the on screen keyboard, but I've disabled that and the problem remains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes please help with this - same issue for me!

Comment: yes please help with this - same issue for me!  is it possible to turn autocorrect off just for bluetooth keyboard?